# two for loops circular walk over

Tags: loops, logic

i have something like this:

*The language is not relevant as i need idea for the logic. I hope my example code is simple enough so it can be read by developer in any lang.*

```
$radius = 5
for $i,(0-$radius),(0+$radius)
    {
    for $j,(0-$radius),(0+$radius)
        {
        do something with $i and $j
        }
    }
```

this will walk my loops like this:
[image]

i need to walk $i and $j like this:
[image]

Is there an easy way to walk 2 loops like that?

The best i came up so far is this:

```
$radius = 10
for $k,0,$radius
    {
    for $i,(0-$k),(0+$k)
        {
        for $j,(0-$k),(0+$k)
            {
            if ($i == (0-$k) || $i == (0+$k) || $j == (0-$k) || $j == (0+$k)) 
                {
                do something with $i and $j
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i have not tested it yet so i'm not sure it will work

Comment: Hi Ken, i apologize but i'm using easyuo language which have no tag here. Also in this case the lang does not matter as i'm looking for the logic and any language is ok for me. The code i provided is simple enough, i hope, so it can be understand by developer of any other language.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, fortunately that is mistake on my side i can fix

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what dimensions you want for the final figure, but this will be roughly correct:

```
$i=0
$j=0
$delta = -1

for $k,1,2*radius
  {
  for $m,1,$k
    {
    do something with $i and $j
    $j += $delta
    }
  for $m,1,$k
    {
    do something with $i and $j
    $i += delta
    }
  delta = -delta
  }
```